# In Dart, is it possible to have a const map of closures?

Tags: dart

I created a literal map of closures, something like:

```
Map<String, Function> mapOfFuncs = {
  'foo': (a, b, c) => ... ,
  'bar': (a, b, c) => ... ,
   ...
}
```

All good so far. Then I wanted to make this map `const`, as it is global within my program and should never be modified.

```
const Map<String, Function> MAP_OF_FUNCS = const {
  'foo': (a, b, c) => ... ,
  'bar': (a, b, c) => ... ,
   ...
}
```

Dart chokes on this as the literal closures in the map are not `const`.

On Dartpad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/817d2cfd141b0a56fc7d

I would have thought that literal closures are `const`. Is there a way to make them so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Closures aren't supported in const expressions. There is an open issue https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/4596 and https://github.com/Pajn/dep-const-function-literals/issues/1

If you create static functions instead, you can reference them in const map literals,but you currently can't define them inline.

Comment: Great finding, i placed callback comments into the issues so the correct answers might be pushed in the future by the authors. Otherwise keep pulling the information ;)

Comment: I was trying static constant closures. Static functions trick didn't strike me lol.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect this might not be possible, take a look at this code:

```
int test1(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a;
}
int test2(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
  return a;
}

const Function f1 = test1;
const Function f2 = (final a,b,c) => a;

const Map<String, Function> MAP_OF_FUNCS = const {
  'foo': test1,
  'fam': test2,
  'bam': f1,
  'bar': f2
};
```

Only the first two versions referencing the static method references `test1` and `test2` work in this constellation. Even `f1` produces a compilation error, **UPDATE** but compiles using dartJS as @irn from the comments pointed out. Then it is unclear why the version with `f2` doesn't work.

So probably it is the assignment operator which is not able to produce a statically compiled reference for a given constant lambda expression or a static method reference for its RHS (right hand side) argument.

[The documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#variables) pointed me in testing the `static const` combination, but this generally only works on non top level elements like class members. Thus adding a new class makes it possible to test this.

```
class A {
  static const Function a1 = test1;
  static const Function a2 = (final a, final b, final c) => a;
}
const Map<String, Function> MAP_OF_FUNCS = const {
  'foo': A.a1,
  'bar': A.a2
};
```

However, these function definitions are valid but assigning it to the map fails as before. The documentation about maps under the [built in types](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#built-in-types) section shows how to create a compile time constant map using the `final` keyword.

```
final constantMap = const {
  2: 'helium',
  10: 'neon',
  18: 'argon',
};
```

Unfortunately, this approach has the same drawback. It might corellate with the minification limitations of symbols:

> A Symbol object represents an operator or identifier declared in a Dart program. You might never need to use symbols, but they’re invaluable for APIs that refer to identifiers by name, because minification changes identifier names but not identifier symbols.
> ...
> Symbol literals are compile-time constants.
>
> For more information on symbols, see [dart:mirrors - reflection](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch03.html#dartmirrors---reflection).

Maybe someone else has a better idea, but for me this seems not possible for the moment.

Comment: The `f1` constant should be constant, and dart2js has no problem compiling it, so it seems like an analyzer bug to get a warning for it.

Comment: @lrn Updated the answer.

Comment: The reason `f2` doesn't work is that a function expression is not a compile-time constant expression. The specification lists the possible compile-time constant expressions, and function expressions are not among them, and the initializer expression of a const variable must be a compile-time constant expression.